# VB Validation if Date Falls between Range

Tags: vb.net, date, for-loop, if-statement, datatable

I am wondering if some one might be able to assist me with my VB code.  I believe I am close, because a lot of the time my code works just fine but I noticed that there might be a weakness to it because at times I get unexpected results.  I am thinking I am missing something pretty basic here so bear with me!

Basically, I am trying to create a simple hotel reservation system in a Data Table for a VB project that I created just playing around in my spare time.

What I hope to be able to accomplish is for a user to be able to select a room number from a list box then pick an arrival and departure date.  After this happens and they click a button I want the program to be able to compare the Room Number along with the beginning date of the reservation and the end date of the reservation with the room number, beginning Dates and end dates in each row already inside of the Data Table.  Anyway, here is basically how my If Statement is structured so far:

```
For Each data As DataRow In dtRoomReserveData.Rows
     If data.Item("RoomNum").ToString.Contains(lstSelectRoomNum.Text) AndAlso data.Item("DateArrive") >= dateArrive.Value.Date AndAlso dr2.Item("DateArrive") <= dateLeave.Value.Date Then
         'if there is a reservation in room exists during that Date range display error message to user:
         MessageBox.Show("Sorry!  That room is already reserved during that date range!")
         Exit Sub
     End If
Next
```

Any help offered is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So did I do something really dumb to the point no one is willing to offer any help, or is it too complex?

Comment: Reason why you don't get any answers is that reading through your question I still don't know what is the problem you are facing? What is not working? As a side note. I would never recommend the use of datatable in something like this, create objects which are strongly typed, will make your life so much easier and robust. As it is your code is not strongly typer, for example data.Item("DateArrive") will return type object but you use it as it is date, it works since you don't have option strict on. If you had it would not even build.

Comment: @Esko The thing that is wrong is that sometimes the logic fails and a new row is inserted with that room number during the date range.  I understand there are better ways to do this, but I need to do it this way if possible.

Comment: @Esko I am just wondering what could be done to improve the logic?

Comment: Is this a windows application or a web application? Have you considered what happens when selected room is "1" and room number "11" is been evaluated? String "11" contains "1", so you should just compare it the strings are equal and not use contains. This does not resolve your issue tho, it will only give false positives. Also your logic on the dates can not work, you are not comparing the departuredates at all. If there is reservation for 28.6-29.6 and somebody wants to reserve 29.6. Your test will fail, 28.6 is not greater or equal to 29.6. Please review your logic.

Comment: @Esko thanks for the advice.  I took it and what I ended up doing was creating a method that checks if a date range falls between and sets a global variable to true if it falls between and false if it does not fall between.  Now I am having trouble taking into account the second date if for example the date is after the dates.  Do you have any recommendations for how to check two dates and if one is beyond or before the dates then I can run another test and have it fail and not add a record to the Data Table?  I will keep thinking, I have some ideas but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Esko I think I can have two booleans inside of my Add Reservation method that will be updated after each date is tested and if both are false (meaning that both are not between the date range) then it will add a reservation.  If one or the other is true then it will not add a new reservation.  I think I might still be missing the case where a date starts before and ends after though.  What are your thoughts?

Comment: @Esko I think I figured this out. I have an idea I'll work on it again in the next few days. Don't give me any hints I think I got this. Thanks for your help.